# Design an algorithm (give pseudo code) that given a binary tree computes the num

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, nodes, computer-science

**Design an algorithm (give pseudo code) that given a binary tree computes the number of nodes with two children. What is the running time of your algorithm**

I reattempted my question, anyone know if I what I presented is correct?
Here is what I've done so far. Is this correct?

```
Function find2Children(T)
Input: a binary search, Tree
Output: number of nodes w / two children

count = 0
inOrderWalk(T)
if((leaf[x] ! = NULL)) && (right[x] ! = NULL))
  count ++
return count
```

we only have to search through a tree of n nodes so O(n) is my TC.

Comment: What does `inOrderWalk` do? This can be solved with a depth first search

Comment: (@ZoffDino: an [in-order-walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-order_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29) would visit the nodes of an ordered/search tree depth first …) _If_ you were guaranteed no nodes with just one descendant, you could just count the internal nodes (checking the presence of just one child …), or the leaves (of which there are one more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using recursion and depth-first search:

```
Function find2Children(T, startNode)
Input: a binary tree, the node to start searching
Output: number of nodes w / two children

if (startNode == NULL) {
    return 0
}

(left, right) = (left[startNode], right[startNode])

count  = (left != NULL) && (right != NULL) ? 1 : 0
count += find2Children(tree, left) + find2Children(tree, right)

return count
```

Or a breadth-first search without recursion:

```
Function find2Children(T)
nodesToCheck = {rootNode}
i = 0
count = 0

while i < nodesToCheck.length {
    x = nodesToCheck[i]
    (left, right) = (left[x], right[x])
    count += (left != NULL) && (right != NULL) ? 1 : 0
    if (left  != NULL) nodesToCheck.add(left)
    if (right != NULL) nodesToCheck.add(right)

    i++
}
```

Both are `O(n)`.

Comment: That DFS doesn't look right; it overlooks any node-with-two-children that is a descendant  of a node-with-only-one-child.

Comment: That BFS doesn't look right; it overlooks any node-with-two-children that is a descendant of a node-with-only-one-child:-/

Comment: @greybeard thanks. I fixed it last night but forgot to copy the new code in. Should code when half-asleep.

Answer (score 0):

rThis is an O(n) algorithm. You can do the computation using any of the tree traversal algorithms (in-order, post-order, or pre-order). Below is a pre-order traversal.

```
find2Children(node)
  if  node == NULL or node.isLeaf()
    return 0

 if node.left != NULL and node.right !=NULL
   return 1+find2Children(node.left)+find2Children(node.right)
 else
  return find2Children(node.left)+find2Children(node.right)
```